# Проблемы с работой __unicode__ в Django

Tags: python, django, unicode

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    group = models.ForeignKey(CategoryGroup)

    def __unicode__ (self):
        return self.title
```

Есть такой код, по идее в админке должно отображаться название категории, вместо этого "Category object" - так, как будто метода юникод нет вообще. В чем может быть проблема?
Django 1.8.2

Comment: Какая версия Python?

Comment: Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Answer (score 2):

Все дело в различных версиях Python.

Если Вы используете Python 2.x, то Вы должны переопределить метод `__unicode__`. Переопределять `__str__` нет необходимости, потому что по-умолчанию он вызывает метод `__unicode__`:

```
def __str__(self):
    if six.PY2 and hasattr(self, '__unicode__'):
        return force_text(self).encode('utf-8')
    return '%s object' % self.__class__.__name__
```

Если Вы используете Python 3.x, то Вы должны переопределить метод `__str__`.

Если Вы пишете кросс-версионное решение, то Вы можете воспользоваться декоратором `python_2_unicode_compatible`:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class MyClass(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return "Instance of my class"
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась заменой **unicode** на **str**
Подробнее о разнице в методах: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/